# chef deploy resource, run in local mode, fails with error - Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_readlink

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I would like to test my Chef recipes locally before I upload them to the Chef server.

I have set up Vagrant on my computer and synced several directories on it to the vagrant guest vm.

1. The project that contains the Chef cookbooks is synced to the `/vagrant` directory in the Vagrant guest vm.
2. The project I would like to deploy is synced to the `/home/vagrant/src/current`directory in the guest vm.

To run the `chef-client` in local mode, I am doing the following.

1. Starting the vagrant box and `ssh`-ing into it.
2. Running the following commands in the guest vm.

   `$ cd /vagrant
   $ sudo chef-client -o 'recipe[cookbook-name::deploy]' -z`

The recipe fails with the following error.

`Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_readlink - /home/vagrant/src/current`

This recipe only fails when I try to run it on my vagrant box in local mode. It does not fail on the servers where the structure is slightly different. In the servers, we follow the structure laid out in https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html where the `current` directory is a link to some release in the `releases` directory.

I'd like to better understand this error and get suggestions on how to make the recipe work in local mode.

Answer (score 0):

The way to test Chef recipes is with Test Kitchen, which supports Vagrant as a driver plugin but handles the file sync for you more carefully than Vagrant itself does.